# Creating Model for Database View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

To create my model i followed the below steps

1. I have already have the database so i added an ADO model to my Project under Model folder.
2. ADO model created the classes for me and i can use them.

I have created a view(not View of MVC) in my DB. But when i am trying to add my ADO model it is failed since it has no Primary key. 
Now i am trying to access my DbView. What is the best solution for this ? I  am not able to use LinqtoSql since my DB is Oracle. 
The other option that i can write a model class to access my DbView ? But how can i write ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. If one of my column has "not null" property, EF define this coloum n as a PK. So i define a new column in my view and generate GUID for this column. 
I think it will help someone . 
Regards.